How to establish UART communication between Raspberry Pi4 and Arduino UNO using TX/RX pins?
I'm trying to establish UART communication between a Raspberry Pi 4 and an Arduino UNO via TX/RX pins. The goal is to send a signal from the Arduino when a button is pressed and receive it on the Raspberry Pi to control an LED.
I Connected the grounds of both devices, and the TX with RX of the other device, and pluged the Arduino uno to my PC to pwor it and to upload the code from arduino IDE
Here's the arduino code
int buttonPin = 8;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("1");
  } else {
    Serial.println("0");
  }
  delay(100);
}

And here is the Raspberry code
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600)
ledPin = 21

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(ledPin, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
        print(f"Received: {data}")
        if data == "1":
            GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        elif data == "0":
            GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.LOW)

I’ve already tried everything, I Disabled the login shell over serial and enabled UART hardware On raspi-config
The Arduino works perfectly; it sends "1" when the button is pressed and "0" when released, as verified through the serial monitor.
I also tested the Raspberry Pi UART using minicom, but nothing is displayed—neither the data from the Arduino nor even the echo when typing.
here is the circuit
Raspberry and Arduino 

The code looks okay on both sides, the question are 1) where exact you connect to RPI 4 header (what GPIO pins)? 2) RPI interface is 3.3V, while Uno is 5V, do you have any level shifter in between?

Raspberry Pi TX (GPIO 14)  to   Arduino RX
Raspberry Pi RX (GPIO 15)   to  Arduino TX
I connected the Raspberry Pi and Arduino GND pins together.
However, I am powering the Raspberry Pi via its standard power adapter and the Arduino via USB connected to my PC. Could this ground setup be causing the communication issue? Do I need to power the Arduino directly from the Raspberry Pi instead?   , the LED is connected to raspberry (GPIO21) and Pushbutton to arduino D8
